# Introduction books for ROS INDIGO

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am pretty new to ROS and would like to have some books for introduction parts. I know there are plenty of tutorials in the net, but i just prefer books.

I already found following book:

Learning ROS for Robotics Programmin.

But this book is based on ROS Fuerte I guees.

Do you have any suggestions.

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173898/introduction-books-for-ros-indigo/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of now, ROS by Example is the latest textbook I believe you can find. Here is link: http://www.ros.org/news/2012/09/new-book-ros-by-example.html

But it is for groovy, newer version then fuerte

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-08-05**:
There is a newer version http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-hydro-volume-1/ebook/product-21393108.html for Hydro

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-05**:
Yes this is the new version, however material is the same, just the book is updated for catkin workspaces instead of rosbuild.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also take a look at "[A gentle Introduction to ROS](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/)" by Jason M. O'Kane. Even though it is written with Hydro in mind it still valid for the basic stuff.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2